# non-boolean (UInt16) used in boolean context

Tags: julia

I'm getting an error:
TypeError: non-boolean (UInt16) used in boolean context

After some debugging the error is coming from this while loop.

```
current_value = UInt16(6)
bit = UInt16(8)
while (current_value & bit)
    bit >>= 1
end
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Oh hey Jim — welcome to the bright new future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing it appears that while loops in Julia don't default to testing for non-zero as true. So I needed to add `!=0` explicitly.

```
current_value = UInt16(6)
bit = UInt16(8)
while (current_value & bit != 0)
    bit >>= 1
end
```

Comment: See https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/control-flow/#man-conditional-evaluation-1 "Unlike C, MATLAB, Perl, Python, and Ruby – but like Java, and a few other stricter, typed languages – it is an error if the value of a conditional expression is anything but true or false"